# Using mime_content_type in combination with ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, mime-types, advanced-custom-fields, data-uri

I have this function for getting the data URI of an image:

```
function get_dataURI($image){
    $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
    $src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;
    echo $src;
}
```

Now I want to use it in combination with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin in WordPress, but it isn't working:

```
<img src="<?php get_dataURI(get_sub_field('author_image')); ?>" height="auto" />
```

If I remove the mime_content_type part of the function, it works, but then it doesn't give a correct data URI.

Here is the error:

```
mime_content_type(): Failed identify data 0:(null) in [FUNCTIONS.PHP FILE PATH] on line 322
```

UPDATE: I noticed that the errors are there, because the function can't find the image path's. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
This one is works for regular sites and wordpress sites that use the ACF plugin to get images:

```
function get_dataURI($image){
    preg_match('/(png|jpe?g)/', $image, $matches);
    $match = $matches[0];
    $imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
    $src = 'data:image/'.$match.';base64,'.$imageData;
    echo $src;
}
```